# Setup Windows 10 IoT with Hurricane Electric's IPv6 Tunnel

Tags: windows-iot, ipv6

I just bought a Raspberry Pi 3 and I'd like to install Windows 10 IoT on it as I'm a Microsoft fan.

I've been using a Pi B as an IPv6 tunnel machine with Tunnelbroker.net but have been using Raspian. Now I'd like to use Windows 10 with my new Pi and use that as tunnel.

How to set up a 6in4 tunnel in Windows 10 IoT on a Raspberry Pi 3 model B?

Comment: Probably not supported with what you want. Probably need to look for a slightly different solution. It is great you are a MS fan.. but if it works on Rasbian then why change to WinIoT? (apart from experimenting which I completely understand)